# How to make a git branch pull/fetch from different remote than push by default?

Tags: git, github

I have forked a github repo and cloned it locally. I have added upstream remote pointing to original repo that I forked. Currently I do following to bring my fork up to date with original repo

```
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git pull --rebase upstream/master
git push origin master
```

I want to be able to just do

```
git fetch           --> should fetch from UPSTREAM remote
git rebase          --> should rebase onto upstream/master
git push            --> should push to ORIGIN remote
```

I tried doing

```
git branch -u upstream/master master
```

This set my master branch to track upstream/master, so git fetch and git rebase work without specifying "upstream" in the command, but this also made "upstream" as remote that "git push" will push to by default.

Can I do something to set ORIGIN as default push remote and "UPSTREAM" as default fetch/pull remote?

Comment: You might have success with the URL config option `pushInsteadOf`

Comment: `git remote add origin git_repo_address` after that `git push origin master`